# Visual Studio settings so that catch statement handles C++ exception?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, exception

I have a C++ project in VS2012 and in the main() function I surround it with a try-catch statement. Something simple like:

```
int main(){
    try{
        //do stuff
    }
    catch(exception& e){
       std::cout << e.what() <<std::endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

However when I run my program the debugger goes to a Microsoft Windows runtime source file because an exception has been thrown. It asks me whether I wish to break or continue (I dont want to do either, I just want the std::cout code in my catch statement to execute).

Now I know there are settings in Debug -> Exceptions and I have constantly changed these and it doesn't seem to change anything. I went to Options -> Debugging and ticked "Just my code" etc.

Could somebody please help?

Comment: I believe you want to continue. Then disable breaking on c++ exceptions from debug / exceptions menu so you do not get the dialog in the future. There should be a checkbox checked for std::exception

Comment: @drescherjm In the debug-> exceptions should I untick "thrown" AND "user-unhandled" tickboxes, for both "C++ Exceptions" AND "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"?

Comment: I do not use CLR so I don't bother with that setting and only use the C++ settings either by disabling the whole category or individual exceptions. Although these days most every exception I deal with is a std::exception. For some reason I do not currently see the user-unhandled in my VS2012.

Comment: @drescherjm you have to go options -> debugging and tick "Just my code" to see them. So I shound untick the boxes for C++ Exceptions basically?

Comment: Yes. untick the options for C++ exceptions.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) My "user unhandled" tickbox is ticked and greyed-out. 2) I unticked the "thrown" tickbox, run the code, the dialog box appears but when i click "continue" it keeps re-showing me the same dialog box (forcing me to select "break")